# need some tips about distributed c# desktop application

Tags: c#

my doubt is the following,  I have a network with 5 pcs, each machine has XP installed, I don't know much about distributed desktop applications, so what i want is to create a C# application using sql server 2005 database and visual studio 2008. I want that each pc can have access to create/update/delete data on the one XP machine that will store the database files.  Do i need WServer2003 or any special network technology??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to install SQL Server on one of the computers and configure its firewall.